# Доработка алгоритма шифрования с использованием XOR

Tags: java, алгоритм, шифрование

Имеем класс, у которого есть два метода: один шифрует, другой дешифрует

```
public class Calculate {


// шифрует
public static byte[] encrypt(String text, String keyWord)
{
    byte[] arr = text.getBytes();
    byte[] keyarr = keyWord.getBytes();
    byte[] result = new byte[arr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = (byte) (arr[i] ^ keyarr[i % keyarr.length]);
    }
    return result;
}

// дешифрует
public static String decrypt(byte[] text, String keyWord)
{
    byte[] result  = new byte[text.length];
    byte[] keyarr = keyWord.getBytes();
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length;i++)
    {
        result[i] = (byte) (text[i] ^ keyarr[i% keyarr.length]);
    }
    return new String(result);
}

}
```

А процесс шифровки-дешифровки выглядит следующим образом:

```
    String mesage = "Привет мир";
    byte[] m = Calculate.encrypt(mesage, "stack_overlow");
    for (byte i : m) System.out.print(i);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(Calculate.decrypt(m, "stack_overlow"));
```

Данный алгоритм работает, но не так, как мне нужно. Проблема состоит в том, что если я просто захочу дешифровать какое-то сообщение,

**Например:**

```
 String message = "-93-21-80-29-69-25-65-60-75-57-67-1987-93-56-79-37-70-33"; // это и есть "Привет мир"
 System.out.println(Calculate.decrypt(message, "stack_overlow")); // дешифрование сообщение "Привет мир"
```

то у меня ничего не выйдет из-за того, что метод `decrypt()` принимает не строку, а массив байтов.

*Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы можно было привести обычную строку к массиву байтов при расшифровки?*

Comment: Вам нужно преобразовать массив байтов в строку после зашифровки и обратно, строку в массив байтов перед дешифровкой?

Comment: Не очень понятно, в чем ваша проблема. У вас где-то есть (где?) зашифрованное сообщение - это всегда результат работы encrypt, т. е. массив байтов. Вы его где-то храните или передаете по сети и потом подаете на вход методу decrypt. Если нет такого сообщения - то что вы хотите расшифровывать? Вы пишете "дешифровать любое сообщение без заполнения массива m" - так а что тогда дешифровать-то???? Где сообщение, если массив пуст?

Comment: @pavlofff Да. Т.е для необходимо то, чтобы мне кто-то передал зашифрованное сообщение в в виде текста и я смог потом этот текст правильно дешифровать (т.е как-то преобразовать текст в массив байтов)

Comment: @m.vokhm Я имел в виду то, что мне нужно как-то преобразовать шифрованную строку в массив байтов, иначе мне никак сообщение не расшифровать.

Comment: @SlandShow, умение осознать и сформулировать проблему - едва ли не главный из тех навыков, которыми должен хорошо владеть любой приличный программист:)

Comment: @m.vokhm Понимаю и извиняюсь за такую нелепую попытку описания проблемы. Просто задавать начал этот вопрос вечером, когда мозг уже плохо соображает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зашифрованное сообщение (т. е. массив байтов) можно предавать по сети, хранить в файле и т. д. разными способами -

1. Непосредственно как набор байтов, это легко. Например, в виде двоичного файла - базовые явовские потоки как раз ориентированы в первую очередь на ввод-вывод потоков байтов.
2. В виде строк (`String`). При этом тоже в принципе могут быть два разных подхода

   - получать после шифрования строку из массива байтов конструктором строки `String(byte[] data)` и тогда перед расшифровкой конвертировать строку в массив байтов методом `getBytes()` - это просто, но строки будут нечитаемые, и я не уверен, что все возможные значения байтов можно передавать таким образом (надо проверить)
   - Конвертировать массив байтов в читаемую строку, записывая значения байтов цифрами (типа `"01, 02, -05"`), а перед расшифровкой эту строку "распарсивать", как это на программистском жаргоне называется - т. е. разделять на подстроки по одному байту на подстроку и извлекать значение байта из каждой такой подстроки. При этом в стрку надо включать явные разделители между байтами, поскольку `"1234"` - неоднозначно - `{12, 34}` или `{123, 4}`? Разбивать строки по разделителю можно методом `split()` класса `String`, а конвертировать строку в байт статическим методом `Byte.parseByte(String s)`.

Comment: Т.е можно попробовать конвертировать байты с помощью парсинга?